# Label will not show on GUI

Tags: java, javafx

I have a GUI, however, when I try to add a Label the screen it does not seem to add correctly.

```java
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Label;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class GUI extends Application {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
        Label labe = new Label("Test");
        Button button = new Button("ASDf");
        TilePane tilePane = new TilePane();
        tilePane.getChildren().addAll(labe, button);
        Scene scene = new Scene(tilePane, 100, 100);
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.show();
    }
}
```

I get the following result When I run the above code

[image]

I am running this in IntelliJ with java version 1.7

How do I get my label to show also?

Comment: This code works on Windows 10, Java 8.

Comment: So it might be because I am on a mac?

Comment: Which version of JavaFX do you use ?

Comment: I am not sure, it is the one bundled with Intellij

Comment: My first guess is that the label is there with a with of 0. Try to assign a width of 100.

Comment: Nope, that did nothing. It moved the button off the side though

Comment: Ok, I thought about a bad version of JavaFX associated with Java, (Java 7 should be associated with JavaFX 2.2) but if it was bundled by IntelliJ, that should not be that. Have you tried to add only the `Label` ?

Comment: Yes I have, just a white screen

Comment: You said that it moved the button to the side when you set the label to have a width of 100, that indicates that it might actually be "there". Have you tried to set the font or background to another color? Could it be so that, for some reason, the font is white?

Comment: Changing to black resulted in the same issue

Comment: Works fine for me on OS X 10.13.6 with jdk1.8.0_162 (I needed to add missing imports to get it to compile).  Verify that the code you are running is actually what you posted (with import fixes).  Java 7 and JavaFX 8 are old and unsupported, update your Java version to something more modern and try it again.  If you are using a version of Idea which is bundled with them, update your IDE as well.

Comment: Try to clean und build your project again.